# What is the MTU used for in EIGRP?

Tags: eigrp, mtu

A lot of sources mention that MTU is included in the EIGRP packets but is not actually used for any path selection calculations. I've also read somewhere that it was supposed to be used as a tiebreaker when there were multiple equal-cost paths to reach a destination but that it's not actually used for that either?

May I know, what exactly is the use of MTU in EIGRP? Since it's included in the EIGRP update packets.

Thank you in advance.